# reactjs reusable component throw error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to UI development, trying to split up my components in different files.
This is one of the components that I need to use in some other file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

import {AppBar} from 'material-ui/AppBar';


//injectTapEventPlugin();

class LoginPage extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>This is from the login page</div>
    );
  }
}
export default LoginPage;
```

This is the main page where I am trying to use the above component.
It gives me the following error in the browser

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in
>   components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
>   undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
>   it's defined in

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage.js'

import {RaisedButton, Dialog, FlatButton} from 'material-ui';


injectTapEventPlugin();

//var LoginPage = require('./pages/LoginPage.js');
//class component
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
      <div>
      This is my page
      <LoginPage />
      </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I saw similar error on SO, but they all say that there is some problem in exporting the components, I cant see the same problem as I am exporting the LoginPage component properly and then importing it in the App.js file as well.

Can someone please help here?

Comment: Use your debugger/console.log to check which one (MuiThemeProvider, LoginPage) is undefined and try to fix it.

Comment: What is your project structure? Is your LoginPage.js same directory with the file contains App component?

Comment: @bennygenel yes, its in the same directory

Comment: Your code looks fine if we consider you successfully installed all external libraries you use. Can you add full error message please. There might be some line or file name that can help to determine the error better

Comment: I got it to work for the simple case where I am not using any material-ui. but the minute I paste the code for AppBar in the LoginPgae.js, it again gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

//injectTapEventPlugin();

class LoginPage extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
      <AppBar title="Title" iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more" />     
      </MuiThemeProvider>
      );
  }
}
export default LoginPage;
```

The app page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage.js'

import {RaisedButton, Dialog, FlatButton} from 'material-ui';

injectTapEventPlugin();

//var LoginPage = require('./pages/LoginPage.js');

//class component
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <LoginPage />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {AppBar} from 'material-ui/AppBar';
```

This line is incorrect.

Importing with brackets means that the requested file contains multiple named exports.  This is usually used when importing from an index file.  For material-ui, that would mean this;

```
import { AppBar } from 'material-ui';
```

You could instead import from the 'material-ui/AppBar' file, but this file only declares a single default export, so you would need to import without brackets, like so:

```
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
```